# Debezium + AWS RDS Postgres data syncing not working

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, debezium

We recently shifted one of our Postgres self-managed database (version 10.12) to AWS RDS Postgres (version 10.18). Post this we have been trying to start the CDC pipeline using Kafka connect and Debezium (Pipeline was working fine on self managed database). Although the initial database snapshot gets replicated and pushed into kafka, any new changes occurring at the database level are not getting captured. Below are the steps we used to start the overall CDC pipeline.

1. Start logical replication by changing parameter group  as

   ```
    rds.logical_replication:  1 (RDS was restarted post this step)
   ```
2. Check for other properties as below:

   ```
    listen_address='*'
    wal_level = logical
    max_wal_senders = 10            
    max_replication_slots = 15      
    wal_writer_delay = 10ms
   ```

3. Setup necessary user and permissions for replication using superuser login

   ```
    CREATE ROLE db_replica LOGIN PASSWORD 'xxxxxxx';
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE some_db TO db_replica;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO db_replica;
    CREATE PUBLICATION dbz_publication FOR ALL TABLES;
    GRANT rds_superuser to db_replica;
    GRANT rds_replication to db_replica;
   ```
4. Setup Debezium connector as :

   ```
    curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/ -d '{"name": "db-test", "config": {"connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector", "database.hostname": "HOSTNAME", "database.port": "5432", "database.user": "db_replica", "database.password": "xxxxxxx", "database.dbname" : "some_db", "database.server.name": "db.test", "plugin.name":"pgoutput", "decimal.handling.mode": "double", "heartbeat.interval.ms": "200", "sanitize.field.names": "true"}}'
   ```

We also checked the kafka connect logs and no exception are getting thrown. It continues to print "flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit"

NOTE:

```
    We have another RDS postgres (version 11.12), which has been running a similar pipeline for more than a year and we have not faced any issues.

    We tried creating two test Postgres RDS instances one with version 10.18 and 11.13 and followed the above steps and both the setups worked as per expectations.
```

Can you let us know what may be wrong here or if we have missed out any steps to activate the streaming process at RDS level?

Regards.

Comment: If you created a new PG 10.18 db and followed the same steps and it works but it sounds like there is some type of database configuration difference between the PG 10.18 instance that isn't working and the test database that did.  Have you compared the two environments to determine if there is any type of difference?